# Returning POST message is not appearing where it should

Tags: javascript, php, web

I followed [this great tutorial](https://bootstrapious.com/p/how-to-build-a-working-bootstrap-contact-form) on how to build a contact form. Everything works great except the success/error messages, instead of appearing above the fields like they should they appears in a 'separate page' i.e mysite.com/contacts.php

I copy paste the `contact.php` and just updated $from & $to values and removed the `last name` and `phone` fields from the `fields array`, to`contact.js`i didn't made any changes. the file that is a bit different is the index.php here is the code index.php:

```
<!-- contact -->
       <div class="contact wowload fadeIn">
       <div class="container">
       <h2 class="text-center">Contact us</h2>
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
          <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="contact.php" role="form">
            <div class="messages"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="name" required="required" data-error="enter your name"> 
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input id="email" name="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="email*" required="required">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea id="message" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="message" rows="5" required="required"></textarea>
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>   
               <div>
                   <p class="text-muted"><strong>*</strong> These fields are required.</p>
               </div>                
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-send-o"></i> Submit</button>

            </form>

          </div>
        </div>
       </div>
       </div>
       <!-- contact -->
```

Why the message not appear where it should, Thanks.

Comment: `message not appear where it should` - where do you think the message *should* appear? it's not obvious in your HTML at all ... you need to learn how FORMS work - yes, you get a new page once you submit a form unless you have javascript that intercepts the submit function to do AJAX and other stuff to prevent the default behaviour of forms

Comment: @JaromandaX have you take a look at the tutorial website? - there is a javascript that does AJAX in the contact.js file - because I just copy paste it without any changes I didn't see the point copying it from the website which I linked to my question

Comment: I do not have to look at that tutorial. You have to post relevant code in the question

Comment: My guess is that you have javascript errors - therefore the javascript doesn't run, therefore the form submits without the javascript intervention ... perhaps you should check your browsers **developer tools console** for errors and fix those